# PHP programming logic inquiry

Tags: php, logic, phpexcel

With the help of this community, I just recently solved some issues with PHPExcel reading multiple files through a `foreach()`. Now it seems I've got **logic** issues.

I'm reading some excel files and extracting some data from them. This data are student grades. You can check a [lightly modified code](http://pastebin.com/umuVzb6U) (I didn't paste it here because of quoting issues). `$filelist` is an array with the filenames available in the `$folder` I chose.

Now, while the first and fourth result show me the values of their respective files, all the other results do not (I've tried with 24 files so far). They show me the results from the first file.

What do you think might be happening here?

I guess it's a problem with the way I'm doing it, but I can't figure out the cause.

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: If you need any further data, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What can I say, it looked correct at a first glance. You can move `$header` and `$column` out of the loop though... sorry for not being really helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been something within the files. I had a hard time redoing all the files into a single file with multiple sheets, and the program now works as intended.